# Android : Swipe within fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Could anybody give me a clue in the following situation :

I have an Android 3+ app, which consists of a sofisticated set of interchangably operating activities derived from **ActionBarActivity**. One of them includes a set of fragments derived from **Fragment**, that can be selected by user by means of

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.containerBase, FragmentX.getInstance(0))
    .commit()
```

where

```
FragmentX extends Fragment {
    public static FragmentX getInstance() {
        FragmentX fragment = new FragmentX();
        return fragment;
    }

    public FragmentX() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_x, container, false);
        . . . . . . . .

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        . . . . . . . .
    }
}
```

All fragments (X, Y, Z etc) appear properly and I was happy until it became necessary to modify some fragments so that they can have several subpages, which should be swipable horizontally by user. Other fragments should stay as they are.

Which Android classes could be the optimal choice and how could they be intergrated in my app?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen ViewPager?

Comment: Yes, I have seen it. Regrettably, I did not recognize how to use it in my case... Could you supply a further hint?

Answer (score 0):

The Fragment that needs to have "horizontally swipable subpages" should probably use a ViewPager of some sort. Your use case isn't completely clear but in my experience a ViewPager with another set of fragments provides a nice and flexible solution. Also, if your "child" fragments (those in the ViewPager) are essentially the same but display different data (e.g. a set of event details fragments), this fragment can also be reused. If not, you can use a `switch` or something similar in the ViewPager's `public Fragment getItem(int position)` method.

You should take a look at the [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) which should fit your needs, the linked page also has a nice and detailed example of how to use it. One thing to note here, since you are using fragments within fragments, the fragment which contains the ViewPager will need to use `getSupportChildFragmentManager` instead of the regular `getSupportFragmentManager` to display those fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly I must give some more details about my app.

```
public class BasePage extends ActionBarActivity implements NavigationBase.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
  private int mPage;
  private NavigationBase mNavigationFragment;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    . . . . . . . .
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
    mNavigationFragment = (NavigationBase) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mNavigationFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
  }

  private void setPage() {
    switch(mPage) {
    case 1:
      fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.containerBase, FragmentX.getInstance())
                .commit();
      break;
    case 2:
      fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.containerBase, FragmentY.getInstance())
                .commit();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The **activity_base** layout looks like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="app.BasePage">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/containerBase"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="app.NavigationBase" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

User navigates through current fragments by setting *mPage* and calling *setPage()*.

Now I need to modify the fragment X thus it has several subpages, whereas the fragment Y must stay as it is. Programmatically the classes FragmentX and FragmentY are identical, they display solely different user contents.

I comprehend that **ViewPager** must be a right solution in this scenario. My problem is I do not see *where* to build the **ViewPager** in my current code...